# How do I figure out what rear axle to purchase for new wheel?

Tags: hub, rear-wheel, axle

I have a Voodoo Bizango 2016 and recently purchased a new rear wheel for it as I’m a larger rider and kept popping spokes.

It’s a Halo vortex 29" wheel with a Shimano HG freehub.

I’m trying to start doing work on the bike myself and just finished swapping over the cassette and brake disc when I noticed that there was no space for the quick release skewer to go into.

Do I need to just purchase a new axle and skewer? How do I get the correct size?

[image: Rear hub and cassette]

Comment: This is a thru-axle hub. If your bike has QRs you need adapters for QR that may have come with the wheel or need to be bought separately.

Comment: Looks like you bought the wrong wheel for your bike frame sorry.  I'd talk to your LBS first and see if they can swap it for the right wheel.  Don't bodge this, try the easier options first.

Comment: This bike is tricky, it appears to use a thru axle in the front and still a quick release in the rear. They probably had a surplus of old QR frames but new forks. You need a different wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers. I’ve spoken to the shop and they are sending me a new set of endcones which they think should sort the issue. 

I will let you all know how that goes. 

Fantastic to get so much so help so quickly thanks all.

Comment: Through-axle to QR adapters exist, example https://problemsolversbike.com/products/hubs/thru-axle-qr-adaptor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: Halo like a number of other manufacturers make [conversion kits](https://www.halowheels.com/shop/spares/hub-spares/mt-supadrive-rear-axle-ends/)  for converting between the different rear axle standards on a bike.

That is a 12mm thru axle rear wheel, which has become the new 'standard' for heavy duty mountain bike disciplines, like what the Halo Vortex has been designed for. <strike>I couldn't see any suitable adapters on the Halo website that allows you to convert the wheel, so I'd return the wheel and get something that fits.</strike>

Unfortunately the days where everything was 26" in diameter, 135mm wide and QR compatible are gone. The things that you need to check would be:

- wheel diameter
- axle type (QR or 12mm thru axle)
- rear wheel spacing (135, 142, or 148)
- you may also need to note down rim width depending on the width of tires that you're using

Comment: The vendor sent out the following endcones, I fitted these and it now works like a dream.

[link](https://www.halowheels.com/shop/spares/hub-spares/mt-supadrive-rear-axle-ends/)

Comment: thanks, edited the answer to include the link to the product I missed on the Halo website.